# Add a character or remove a character from a character variable

Tags: sas

I have two different datasets - in one dataset (1) the variable homes has data in the following format "C012" and I have another dataset (2) that has the variable home in the format "012". I need to merge these two datasets together. How do I either add the C into dataset 2 or remove the C from dataset 1?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you add "C" in front of you `home` string variable

```
home = "C"||home;
```

so it would look like this

```
data have;
    input home $ ;
    cards;
012
;
run;

data want;
    set have;
    home = "C"||home;
run;
```

Comment: This did not work. There is more than one row in the homes variable

Comment: I cannot know that, you have not specified that in the question.